# Visual Studio Cordova deployment

Tags: cordova, deployment, visual-studio-2013, google-play, visual-studio-cordova

I have developed a mobile app with cordova plugin of visual studio. How can I package and publish app to google play?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reply to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27041577/visual-studio-2013-update-4-cordova-how-to-export-android-apk-file-to-publish-i) post on the same topic has all the information you need on publishing your app to the Google Play store.